# how to delete mysql records automatically that exist in database for a month

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete mysql table records automatically.My project is a  application for enquiry. A client asks some question through mobile app to server.If person in euquiry doesn't reply,the question must be deleted automatically after a month.how can i do it.Using mysql events ?i am using wampserver.

Comment: A Cronjob is a very easy solution for this

Comment: it may help ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850185/how-to-delete-data-from-database-after-specified-hours-automatically

Comment: I normally write a php script that does the maintenance and run that daily using a task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If a customer ask you to 'delete' a record, you should understand that you should find a better solution. It is not-done to delete records for users, what if you ever want to use that data again?

What you want is to add a few colums. Add a 'start time' value with a date, and add a 'active' record where you can state 1 or 0 for being active or not.

You could run a task to change the active value to 0, and in your application only fetch those who are active.

For MySQL you can use the following:

```
CREATE 
EVENT `your_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
DO BEGIN

UPDATE table SET active = 0 WHERE your_date < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
```

If you really want, you can obvious use DELETE there..

Actually have not tested above code yet, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A client requirement to delete something after a month is a serious requirement.  I would suggest doing two things.  First, add a creation date to each row in the database and access the database using:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.creationdate >= date(now()) - interval 1 month;
```

This ensures that you will get only the appropriate rows in any query.  In fact, you can wrap that in a view and only use the view in your application.

Then, at your leisure, run a job to delete anything older than a month:

```
delete from t
    where t.creationdate < date(now()) - interval 1 month;
```

Using this method, the users will never see an old value, even if you miss running the `delete`.  In addition, you can schedule the `delete` for a quiet time on the server, so it doesn't interfere with other activities.